# retrofit 2, синглттон ? какие еще подходы, паттерны

Tags: android, retrofit2

Смотрю примеры по использованию `retrofit 2` , создают интерфейс и для доступа к нему из любого класса  создают экземпляр интерфейса, в классе наследуемом от Application. Вроде бы удобно. Понадобится 2 разных интерфейса и это не проблема, сделаем два синглтона. Или если интерфейс один и запросы делаются из одного класса, то можно там этот интерфейс и инициализировать.

Мне бы хотелось узнать какие бывают еще ситуации с ретрофит, когда синглтон не стоит реализовывать. Вроде бы retrofit 2 содержит в себе Pattern A (для `REST API`). Этот паттерн предполагает кеширование, сохранение результатов в БД и уведомление об этом, а некий класс уже считывает их с БД.

Всё это выполняется в `retrofit 2` ? думаю нет и мне нужно самому создавать БД. Ведь БД нужна за тем, чтобы сперва сделать запрос в неё и если результата нет, делать запрос по сети?

Answer (score 1):

Текущие рекомендуемые подходы по кэшированию и сохранению данных

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#caching_data
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#persisting_data

Или же еще делать обертку, которая добавляет статусы
 - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum через NetworkBoundResource можно посмотреть в https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample